# How can I do a table join where the composite key is an access number and a date +/- 1 day

Tags: mysql, sql, case, composite-primary-key

I am trying to do a table join where the composite key is an access number and a snapshot date, and the data of interest is Status.  Here's what the simple join looks like:

```
SELECT A.Access_Num, B.Access_Num, A.SNAPSHOT_DATE, B.SNAPSHOT_DATE, B.Status
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Access_Num = B.Access_Numb AND A.SNAPSHOT_DATE = B.SNAPSHOT_DATE
```

My obstacle is that the data of interest Status is not populated on the exact match for SNAPSHOT_DATE (20% of the time).  Sometimes it varies by +/- 1 from the SNAPSHOT_DATE in table A.  There's still a record match, but table B will just return NA.

I am trying to write a join case that examines if Status returns as NA, to look at a composite key from the previous day for Table_B, and a composite key from the next day to see if there's a valid value available (i.e., not NA).

In the table below, I would want the query to recognize that row 3 returns an NA, so then it looks at the previous or next day to find a valid value.  It should pick up that row 4 has a non-NA value, and return that one.

```
Row     A.Access_Num    B.Access_Num    A.SNAPSHOT_DATE    B.SNAPSHOT_DATE  B.STATUS
1       11              11              12-12-2018         12-12-2018       Y
2       11              11              12-13-2018         12-13-2018       Y
3       13              13              12-05-2018         12-05-2018       NA             
4       13              13                                 12-06-2018       Y
```

Comment: You can join to B twice, and make values from the first B part of the join criteria for the second join. However, if there is one the day before and one the day after, you should be joining separately for each (3 joins to B total) to prioritize one over the other; otherwise, you'll end up with two results for such rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inequalities in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT A.Access_Num, B.Access_Num, A.SNAPSHOT_DATE, B.SNAPSHOT_DATE, B.Status
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON A.Access_Num = B.Access_Numb AND
        A.SNAPSHOT_DATE >= B.SNAPSHOT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
        A.SNAPSHOT_DATE <= B.SNAPSHOT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```